# How to change foreground color fo a textbox programmaticallly in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I want to change the foreground property of a textbox when it is clicked on. In WPF I could say `textBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Black;`   But in Silverlight you can't use `System.Drawing`. Is there any other way to to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight, you can use [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558629%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance as `Foreground`, for example :

```
textBox1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

Comment: I have been tryin Color instead of Colors all this time.